# odoo showing ValidateError: _description_searchable while parsing

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

In my custom module it is showing error as

```
    ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
_description_searchable" while parsing
```

My code is as follows,

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="room-booking-calender">
   <field name="name">Book.Room</field>
   <field name="model">book.meeting</field>
   <field name="type">calendar</field>
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <calendar string="Booking Status" color="state" date_start="start_time" date_stop="end_time" mode="week">
          <field name="name"/>
          <field name="meeting_room"/>
      </calendar>
   </field>
 </record>
```

My code was working properly, but suddenly this error came. How to rectify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this error in odoo when multiple compute fields are used. Mostly this error will be associated with compute fields. Check your fields especially compute fields (In old API functional fields)

Answer (score 4):

I have just faced this error and in my case the problem was that I had set `store=False` in a declaration field without the attribute `compute`.

**Wrong**

```
my_field = fields.Char(
   string='My field',
   store=False,
)
```

**Good**

```
my_field = fields.Char(
   string='My field',
   compute='_compute_my_field',
   store=False,
)
```

Comment: you save my time @forvas, in my case I have removed the store=False and the error disappeared.